# Why am I unable to make the external script run in a new window?

Tags: powershell

I built a powershell form that recreates a VM from a snapshot in azure. I have the backing script that does the actual work prepared and it works just fine on its own when I run it. But, when I go to execute it from within the script that generates the form, it either doesn't run or it gets stuck relatively early on in the file and does not complete execution of all the commands. I can validate the parameters are correct when I run it, as one of the buttons on the form calls a different script that validates all of the parameters.

Since one of the subscripts keeps getting stuck in execution, I want to open it in a new window and leave it to finish. However everything I've tried to do either:

- doesn't run the script
- opens a new window but does nothing
- opens then immediately closes the script (i don't see red text in the second it runs). Since total execution is normally 10 minutes, I know it's either crashed or rage-quit on me.

I've also noticed that when I run azureRM commands from within a form, that if I try to execute more than 2 commands to do something it immediately freezes the script regardless of whether or not I open this in ISE or run from CLI. in the snip below, this is what I'm trying to run when i click the button to renanimate/recreate the VM. You'll see that I've commented out a LOT of attempts to make it run on its own.

```
$reanimateButton.add_Click({
    $mySub = ""
    if($RadioButton1.Checked){$mySub = '$subscriptionA'}
    if($RadioButton2.Checked){$mySub = '$subscriptionB'}
    $rgName = $rgMenu.Text
    $vm = $vmNameMenu.Text
    $sa = $storageMenu.text
    $oSnap = $snapOSMenu.Text
    $dSnap = $snapDataMenu.Text
    $opSnap = $snapOptionalMenu.Text
    $vmSize = $vmSizeMenu.Text

    $argumentList = "-subscription $mySub -resourceGroupName $rgName -vmName $vm -diagStorageAcc $sa -snapshotName $oSnap -DataSnapshotName $dSnap -optionalDataSnapName $opSnap -vmSize $vmSize"
    $scriptPath = "C:\azure\vm scripting\Reanimator\Restore-vmFromSnapshot.ps1"

    #cd "C:\azure\vm scripting\Reanimator"

    #.\Restore-vmFromSnapshot.ps1 -subscription $mySub -resourceGroupName $rgName -vmName $vm -diagStorageAcc $sa -snapshotName $oSnap -DataSnapshotName $dSnap -optionalDataSnapName $opSnap -vmSize $vmSize


    #Invoke-expression 'cmd /c start powershell -Command {"& `"$scriptPath`" $argumentList"}'
    #Invoke-Expression "& `"$scriptPath`" $argumentList"
    cmd /c start powershell -Command {"& `"$scriptPath`" $argumentList"}
    #start-process powershell -ArgumentList -NoExit -Command {cd "C:\azure\vm scripting\Reanimator"; .\Restore-vmFromSnapshot.ps1 -subscription $mySub -resourceGroupName $rgName -vmName $vm -diagStorageAcc $sa -snapshotName $oSnap -DataSnapshotName $dSnap -optionalDataSnapName $opSnap -vmSize $vmSize;}

})
```

Comment: Would probably need to see everything on your client to view how it is handling code, however to me personally it sounds like a design issue. How are you managing the form creation? If you are trying to do multiple forms on the same script you'll need to have at minimum a two-pronged system.

Comment: 1.) Backend design, manages data as well as creation of new form processes. Creates configuration files for the form to import from. Can be direct connectors but more experience is required typically.
2.) Form design, manages the gui of form and runs separate from the backend design. Takes in data from config files or a connector.

Comment: If you try to run multiple forms on the script itself it will act weird unless you have it formatted in a very specific way, and can grow out of size very quickly if you are utilizing more than two forms. I prefer having separate scripts for each GUI interface I'm using and having a backend system make updates to each through configuration files.

Comment: "If you try to run multiple forms on the script itself it will act weird unless you have it formatted in a very specific way," 

can you elaborate on what you mean by this? I don't often write forms so I try to keep everything minimal in my design/most efficient with which boxes/menus/radios i use to represent data.

Comment: If you think of it in terms of loops often times running multiple forms is like running a loop in the script. It won't continue or run other aspects of the script unless you terminate the form (similar to loops).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DO NOT** use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

For starting a PowerShell script or command in a new window use `Start-Process`. The reason why your attempt at that didn't work is most likely that PowerShell interpreted `-NoExit` and `-Command` as parameters for `Start-Process` (which don't exist) rather than as arguments for the new PowerShell process. You need to pass the arguments either as a single string

```
Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -ArgumentList "-NoExit -Command {...}"
```

or as an array where parameters like `-NoExit` should be defined as strings.

```
Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -ArgumentList '-NoExit', '-Command', "{...}"
```

With that said, your statement is overly convoluted. A better (simpler) approach is to set the working directory via the respective `Start-Process` parameter and then run the script via `-File`.

```
$workdir = 'C:\azure\vm scripting\Reanimator'
$params  = '-NoExit', '-File', '.\Restore-vmFromSnapshot.ps1',
           '-subscription', $mySub, '-resourceGroupName', $rgName,
           '-vmName', $vm, '-diagStorageAcc', $sa, '-snapshotName', $oSnap,
           '-DataSnapshotName', $dSnap, '-optionalDataSnapName', $opSnap,
           '-vmSize', $vmSize
Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -WorkingDirectory $workdir -ArgumentList $params
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to do the trick with getting it to run. the subscript executes as expected now.

I didn't know you could start-process as one long list like that. TIL.